# how to get last navigation route when app is reloaded in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native

I have a react-native app
and I define one splash screen. when user is Authenticated, it navigate to home and when user is not Authenticated, it navigate to login
its work correctly, but:
I want to when the app is in develop mode and when reloaded, it navigate to last route

can you help me to fix this ux problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the state of navigation, source here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/

```js
import { useNavigationState } from '@react-navigation/native';

const usePreviousRouteName =() => {
    return useNavigationState(state =>
      state.routes[state.index - 1]?.name
        ? state.routes[state.index - 1].name
        : 'None'
    );
}
```